# Why doesnt my UILabel change font?

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts

I've read different answers here about custom fonts in XCode, but I still cant get it to work.

What I've done:

Added it to Plist.
Added it to Copy boundle resources.

If I do:

```
for ( NSString *familyName in [UIFont familyNames] )
    {
        NSLog(@"Family: %@", familyName);
        NSLog(@"Names = %@", [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName]);
    }
```

It will print it:

```
2013-03-26 17:04:52:214 Appname[21704:2311] Family: Patrick Hand
2013-03-26 17:04:52:217 Appname[21704:2311] Names = (
    "PatrickHand-Regular"
)
```

And I've tried to set the font with both:

```
self.usernameLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"PatrickHand-Regular" size:30];
```

and

```
self.usernameLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"PatrickHand" size:30];
```

My most desperate attempt was this:

```
for ( NSString *familyName in [UIFont familyNames] )
    {
        NSLog(@"Family: %@", familyName);
        NSLog(@"Names = %@", [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName]);
        [self.usernameLabel setFont:[[UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName] objectAtIndex:0]];
        if ( [familyName isEqualToString:@"Patrick Hand" ])
        {
        NSLog(@"BREAK!");
        break;
        }
    }
```

But it still doesn't change.

Suggestions what to try?

Comment: Try installing the font on your Mac, open up Font Book, and see what name it shows in there. Is it PatrickHand-Regular?

Comment: It says "PostScript name: PatrickHand-Regular"

Comment: In what method in your controller class are you trying to call `self.usernameLabel.font = ....`? (e.g. `init`, `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear`, etc.)

Comment: I'm guessing you've run a 'Clean' on your project, right?

Comment: In initWithCoder, is that wrong?

Comment: you should do it in viewDidLoad. as initWithCoder unarchives all your outlets etc. *I am not sure abuot ios still learning*

Comment: It worked sweet when moved to viewDidLoad! Thank you, you could write it as an anwer. Also, what could the reason be I cant choose the font from Fonts in storyboard?

Comment: I had this issue when I set the font in the viewDidLoad after it had already been set in the storyboard. Moving it to viewWillAppear worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to change something in the user interface by using an `IBOutlet` instance variable, you need to make sure you call the code at the appropriate time.

For example, let's say you have a class like the following:

```
@interface MDViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *usernameLabel;

@end
```

There is also an `MDViewController.nib` file which holds the UI of the view controller, and let's say you want to set the contents of the label to some value.

Normally, `init` methods like `init` or `initWithCoder:` are called too early in the lifetime of the object to be able to communicate with the objects in the UI, as the nib file has not yet been fully loaded, and your `IBOutlet` instance variables at that point will still be `nil`.

Later on, in methods like `awakeFromNib`, `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear`, and `viewDidAppear`, the `IBOutlets` will be properly set up and you can communicate with the UI objects.

In your case, `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` are probably good points to set this value (which one depends on your specific needs).